# Magento2 Copy Customer name to invoice billing address name

Tags: magento2, orders, customer, invoice, address

- For billing issues i want to use default customer name as same
  billing address in invoice only.
- i.e Customer name is **`John Doe`** and he use **`Johny Doe`** in billing
  address when he order. it is ok for order but when invoice will create it should
  update to **`John Doe`** in billing address in invoice only.
- He may pay by online of offline whatever.

How can i achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

Since the invoice uses the billing adress object of the order you can't save changes in the billing address which should affect only the invoice.

But you can try to use a plugin after the method `getBillingAddress()` in the invoice model (`Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice`) and overwrite the 
name fields (prefix, firstname, lastname etc. depending on your configuration / used fields).

A method like this should work for the suggested approach (don't forget to add the plugin in your `di.xml`) :

```
public function afterGetBillingAddress(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice $subject, $result)
{
    $customer = $subject->getOrder()->getCustomer();
    if ($customer->getId()){
        $result->setFirstname($customer->getFirstname());
        $result->setLastname($customer->getLastname());
        //... add other name fields like prefix, middlename, suffix if needed 
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: i try this but getBillingAddress() is not working to retrive address in core file also

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are meaning with "not working to retreive address in core file also"

Comment: when i comment above function in Invoice.php although i get billing address

Comment: So you have created a plugin class with the method I've suggested in my answer, configured that plugin class in your `di.xml` as plugin to `Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice::getBillingAddress()`, run `bin/magento di:setup:compile` and don't get the changed values if you call `getBillingAddress()` on an invoice object of an order of a registered customer?

Comment: yes it's not working,if even if i change in getBillingAddress nothing affects

Comment: That means that whereever the code you are using is located, it doesn't access the billing address through the invoice object but through the order.